# Error in mysql while importing from csv

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

This is my command line query.

```
mysql> load data local infile "c:\\re\\30-11-08.csv" 
into table powerdata(Date, DG1, DG2, DG3, Dg4, DG5, ChillerPanel1, 
    ChillerPanel2, ChillerPanel3, ChillerPanel4,1st_Floor, 2nd_Floor, 
    3rd_Floor, 4th_Floor, UPS1, UPS2, UPS3, UPS4, UPS5,Server_Power, 
    Cooling_Power) 
    fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'
set Dateformat=str_to_date(Date, '%m/%d/%Y' '%H:%i:%s');
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'set Dateformat=str_to_date(Date' at line 1

I do not know where the error is! Can anyone help me?

Comment: i have mysql 5.0 . to support set clause which one shall i download

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the "set Dateformat=" part is causing the problem. Your column is named "Date" so that part should look like:

```
set Date = str_to_date(@datevar, 'your format')
```

Also see the following code sample in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (column1, @var1)
  SET column2 = @var1/100;
```

BTW: before MySQL 5.0.3 the SET clause is not supported.